# Ignorar el enter (salto de linea) de un textarea

Tags: java

tengo un problema para detectar el enter de un texarea.
Obtengo el contenido de la siguiente forma:

```
String codigo = jTextAreaCodigo.getText();
```

Despues recorro el string caracter por caracter y omito los espacios

```
for(int i = 0; i < codigo.length(); i++) {
    char token = codigo.charAt(i);

    if(token == ' ')
        continue;

    // codigo
}
```

Pero el problema es como detectar cuando en el texarea

Comment: Cual es el fin de esto?, puedes usar ```split()```

Comment: El problema que puedes encontrarte es que un `enter` significa diferentes cosas en sistemas linux, windows o mac... No estoy seguro de si hacer un split por `\n` te servirá, si no, deberás hacer un `split(System.lineSeparator())`, que hará que tu código funcione en cualquier SO. A partir de ahí, tendrás que recorrer cada línea como estabas haciendo antes con todo.

Comment: Estoy diseñando el scanner de mi propio lenguaje de programacion, necesito leer caracter por caracter para detectar secuencias de caracteres y asi saber si esta dentro de la sintaxis de mi lenguaje. Se que puedo usar el split, pero que debo detectar?split("aqui que va?")

Answer (score 0):

puedes ponerle al JTextArea un KeyPressed:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == JTextArea){
        char token = "";
    }
}
```